# Rotation sense of a potentiometer

Tags: resistance, potentiometer

I've been making an audio amplifier, it works well so far after getting the correct components. I'm using a [10K potentiometer with switch](http://www.maplin.co.uk/standard-potentiometers-with-switch-2208) for the volume but I've got a problem. The potentiometer increases resistance as I rotate clockwise... I need it to be the opposite, at the moment when rotating clockwise it works like this:

```
Off - 0 -> 10k
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
Off - 10k -> 0
```

If there a way to reverse the resistance, or have I purchases the wrong pot?

Thanks for your help :-)
Ben

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally a potmeter has three connections. The middle is the wiper which moves over the resistive path, from the left pin to the right one when rotating clockwise. Swap the left and right pin and you should be OK. Important: be sure that it's a **logarithmic** potmeter instead of the regular **linear** ones.

**edit**
I read that the resistance increases if you rotate clockwise, and that you want the reverse. I don't know what the surroundings of the potmeter look like, but for a volume control you normally want to increase the resistance (between the left pin and the wiper) when rotating clockwise. If for some reason you want the reverse you don't want a logarithmic potmeter, but an **anti-logarithmic** one, which is much rarer.

Comment: I think it's linear... although the link (in my question) mentions both log and lin in the spec :S

Comment: @Ben - you can easily check whether it's lin or log. Put the wiper in the halfway position and measure the resistance to one end. If it's 5k then it's lin, if it's far less or far more it's log.

Comment: I measured the resistance at halfway yesterday and it was about 4.6k.. but then even at full it was only 8.9k (something like that, certainly not the full 10k(, so it at halfway it's certainly about 50%. Does this mean swapping the left and right won't work?

Comment: @Ben - Swapping will work, but you'll get poor volume control: the volume will increase very fast in the beginning and only a little at the end of the rotation. A log potmeter will have a smoother response.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I tried it and it does work, reducing resistance as I turn clockwise. This will do me for now, thanks again :-)

Comment: It's worth noting that you can turn a linear pot into a log by using a parallel fixed resistor to ground. Use a fixed resistor about 1/7th to 1/10th of the value of your variable pot and you should get a nice log curve. It'll be a better curve than what you get from a cheap purpose built log pot, they tend to be a rough estimation and often have a really sharp knee on their curve.

Answer (score 3):

Swap the two connections to the ends of the track.